# MySQL .NET Connector documentation confusion

Tags: .net, mysql, blob, mysql-connector

[MySQL 5.0 Connector.NET Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader.html#connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader-getbytes) states:

> GetBytes returns the number of available bytes in the field. In most cases this is the exact length of the field.

However, [MySQL 5.0 Connector.NET Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldatareader-getbytes) lists the return value of `GetBytes` as the number of bytes read into the buffer.

To me this isn't the same thing at all!

Regardless, my question is: what's the most readable construction to get the content from the datasource into a `MemoryStream` object? I'm using the return value from `GetBytes` to increment the data index parameter of the `GetBytes` method but seemingly I keep overrunning the field because I get `IndexOutOfRangeException` being thrown.

Comment: please don't delete good questions like: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7570740/650492

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that the documentation for `MySqlDataReader` leaves a lot to be desired.

When you pass `null` as the `buffer` argument, `GetBytes` returns the total length of the field. When you pass a non-null `buffer` argument, `GetBytes` returns the number of bytes that were written into the buffer.

```
long length = yourReader.GetBytes(columnOrdinal, 0, null, 0, 0);
long offset = 0;
var buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];    // 4KB buffer
var ms = new MemoryStream();

while (length > 0)
{
    long bytesRead = yourReader.GetBytes(columnOrdinal, offset, buffer, 0,
                                         (int)Math.Min(length, buffer.Length));

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, (int)bytesRead);
        length -= bytesRead;
        offset += bytesRead;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified Luke's code a bit (and upvoted).  Not saying it's better, just different.  Only works for fields less than 2GB.

```
private static byte[] ReadBinaryField(MySqlDataReader reader, int fieldIndex)
{
    var remaining = (int)reader.GetBytes(fieldIndex, 0, null, 0, 0);
    var bytes = new byte[remaining];

    while (remaining > 0)
    {
        var offset = bytes.Length - remaining;
        var bytesRead = (int)reader.GetBytes(fieldIndex, offset, bytes, offset, remaining);
        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            // Hopefully this is impossible
            throw new Exception("Could not read the rest of the field.");
        }
        remaining -= bytesRead;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

You could make it an extension method, if you like.